# How can I use ConfigurationPropertyAttribute in a .Net Core project targeting the net462 framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm trying to compile a small project, which was created with Visual Studio 2017 as a normal .Net project, using Visual Studio Code. One of the class, [ConfigurationPropertyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationpropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), cannot be found and I wonder which reference I should add to make it compile.

I tried searching for this class using reverse search in NuGet but it doesn't seem to exist.

Here is my .Net Core project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.extensions.configuration" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My ultimate goal is simply to be able to compile and debug an old project using Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio 2017 without necessarily using .Net Core as it is still lacking many features. I thought that by targeting net462 I would get access to everything from .Net 4.6.2 but it doesn't seem so. Did I miss something or is there something I didn't understand properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .csproj file needs to add a Reference `System.Configuration` not a PackageRefrence `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was now able to compile my project ! The sad thing though is that I cannot even debug this project with Visual Studio Code because it is not targeting .Net Core. So there is actually no point to use the new project format if I'll use VS2017 anyways as my project uses some classes which don't seem to have been ported to .Net Core yet so some code need to be rewritten... I wished that this Reference this was documented somewhere, all I see in tutorials is PackageReference!

Comment: You can find some documentation in the documentation for MSBuild https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items However when creating this example I just used the GUI of right clicking on the project in the solution explorer and chose the "Add reference" option.

Comment: I see, but this is in VS2017, there is no such Add Reference in VS Code, or at least I couldn't find it. Thanks !